# Software to create "image folder thumbnail"

Tags: images

I need to create a big thumbnail, which would contain thumbnails for a list of images, laid out in a table.

For ex.

```
img1 img2 img3
img4 img5 img6
img7 img8 img9
```

Is there automatic tool to do that kind of job?

Answer (score 0):

You might get a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/

It provides many capabilities including "montage" (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php)